# Autosizing didn't work with UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a table view and I want to set an image to my `UITableviewCell`. I set autosizing for my imageView in Storyboard but when I run it on Simulator that image didn't stand at the correct position as I want.

I want this stand like this in Storyboard:

[image]

But in simulator it display differently, like this:

[image]

This is how I set the image in my TableViewCell

```
@interface CBBookDetailCell : UITableViewCell
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
-(void) setBookImage:(NSString*) imageLocal;
@end


@implementation CBBookDetailCell

-(void) setBookImage:(NSString*) imageLocal{
  self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageLocal];
}
…
@end
```

and I call it in CellfromIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier;

    if( indexPath.row == 0){
        cellIdentifier = @"BookDetailCell";
        CBBookDetailCell *cell ;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setBookImage:imageLocal];
        return cell;
    } else{
        cellIdentifier = @"ChapterCell";
        CBChapterCell *cell;
        CBChapter *chapter = [chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setChapterDetail:chapter.name PublishDate:chapter.publishDate];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you programmatically set the image?

Comment: I edited my Question above. Please see it. Thanks

Comment: Can you include cellforrowatindexpath()? And is there anywhere else in your VC that you're interacting with self.imageView?

Comment: I just only set my image in CBBookDetailCell.h  .In cellforrowatindexpath() I just call my cell. Please see my edited quest.

Answer (score 0):

You're resizing the view itself, not the image inside of the view. Try this instead:

[image]

Comment: That's one I already set for my image. The result is still the same:(